# Cannot Find GeneratorDrivenPropertyChecks Trait

Tags: scala, scalatest

I have these test dependencies defined

```scala
/ Test Dependencies
lazy val wiremock             = "com.github.tomakehurst"      % "wiremock-jre8"             % "2.25.1"
lazy val playTest             = "com.typesafe.play"          %% "play-test"                 % "2.8.1"
lazy val scalaTestPlusPlay    = "org.scalatestplus.play"     %% "scalatestplus-play"        % "5.1.0"
lazy val mockito              = "org.mockito"                %% "mockito-scala"             % "1.10.2"
lazy val scalamock            = "org.scalamock"              %% "scalamock"                 % "4.4.0"
lazy val scalacheck_shapeless = "com.github.alexarchambault" %% "scalacheck-shapeless_1.14" % "1.2.3"
lazy val scalatest            = "org.scalatest"              %% "scalatest"                 % "3.1.1"
```

But I cannot find this trait to mix into my test spec class: [GeneratorDrivenPropertyChecks](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/generator_driven_property_checks). I am not sure what I am missing here in terms of dependencies. Under `org.scalatest.prop` I don't see this trait. I only see TableDrivenPropertyChecks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`GeneratorDrivenPropertyChecks` seems to have been [removed](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/issues/1735#issuecomment-564679176) in ScalaTest 3.1.0

> We made it private so that it would not hold up the 3.1.0 release any
>   longer. I wanted to investigate a better way to integrate shrinking,
>   as has been done by tools such as Hedgehog. The 3.2.0 release we
>   wanted to be exactly the same as 3.1.0 except for modularization.
>   After that we plan to complete and release ScalaTest's Generator.
>   Meanwhile we figured everyone would continue to use
>   ScalaCheckDrivenPropertyChecks and Gen, which is available here:
>
> https://github.com/scalatest/scalatestplus-scalacheck

Instead try using `ScalaCheckDrivenPropertyChecks` like so

```
import org.scalacheck.Gen
import org.scalatest.flatspec.AnyFlatSpec
import org.scalatest.matchers.should.Matchers
import org.scalatestplus.scalacheck.ScalaCheckDrivenPropertyChecks

class HelloSpec extends AnyFlatSpec with Matchers with ScalaCheckDrivenPropertyChecks {
  "ScalaCheckDrivenPropertyChecks" should "provide forAll" in {
    forAll(Gen.choose(1, 100)) { i =>
      i shouldBe i
    }
  }
}
```

where

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalatestplus" %% "scalacheck-1-14" % "3.1.1.1" % Test,
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.1.1" % Test
)
```

Comment: We're at version 3.2.0, and [the docs](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/property_based_testing) still refer to the old non-existent traits. It's taken me 25 minutes to find this answer after trying to figure it out in various blogs and their GitHub :/ Hvala Mario!

Comment: @Zoltán The docs seem to be drifting slightly out-of-date as some significant changes were introduced to prepare for 3.2.0. I am guessing now that 3.2.0 is out, the docs will begin to catch up (note I have no evidence for that). Personally, for most up-to-date information I follow links at https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/releases.

Comment: These are major backwards-incompatible change and they really seem to call for a major version bump. They don't appear to be described, so it's hard to go through and find 1-1 replacements for GeneratorDrivenPropertyChecks, PropSpec, etc.

Comment: The above seemed to be not found but this worked for me: `"org.scalatestplus" % "scalacheck-1-15_3" % "3.2.10.0" % "test"`